# http streaming

Tags: http, streaming

is http streaming possible without using any streaming servers?

Comment: Sure, but you need also segmenter.

Answer (score 1):

Of course. You can output and flush, it gets to client before you end the script, thus it's streaming.

Answer (score 1):

For live streaming, only segmented, like Apple HLS, other variants of segmented HLS (like OSMF) are not widely supported at the moment.
IIS from microsoft can also do smooth streaming (and Apple HLS as well).
Apple HLS can be supported on any web server when you pre-segment stream to chunks and just upload to web server path.

For VoD streaming, there is lot's of modules for all web servers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although libraries have varying level of support. What needs to be used is "http chunking", such that lib does not try to buffer the whole request/response in memory (to computed the content length header) and instead indicate content comes in chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,not only its possible but has been implemented by various media server companies, only reason they still make usage of servers because of commercial purpose. Basically the content you want to stream should be divided into chunks/packets and then client machine can request those chunks via simple HTTP Get Requests.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have WebSockets available you can actually get quite low-latency streaming for low-fps scenarios by sending video frames as jpegs.

You can also send audio separately and play it using WebAudio on your browser. I imagine it could work for scenarios where you do not require perfect audio-video sync.

Another approach is to stream MPEG chunks through WebSockets, decode them in JS using jsmpeg and render to a canvas. You can find more here (video-only):

http://phoboslab.org/log/2013/09/html5-live-video-streaming-via-websockets

Comment: “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”

Comment: Updated as suggested. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

yes, the answer to your problem with http streaming is MPEG-DASH tech